# Benefit of having an abstract class implement an interface?

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589147/interface-abstract-or-just-virtual-methods/7589229#7589229) on if I should implement interfaces or abstract classes.  Scottm gave answer suggesting I use both, but I am still unsure why I would want to do this.  Is there a benefit in the long term? What are advantages of doing it that way?

Here are some benefits I think:

- I can add methods to abstract class without breaking the implementation, but with interfaces, I would break it.
- I can inherit from multiple interfaces, but only one abstract class
- Abstract class allows me to define standard behavior, but override it if I want to.

Here is another question.  If I implement an interface, should the interface only contain methods that all sub-classes can do? And if I need extra logic, I would create a concrete class or abstract class with more specific implementations.

Comment: I wonder if .net 5.0 might ease the restrictions by allowing an interface to be paired with a static base class, and allow the interface to declare default implementations for methods and properties using static class members.  I wouldn't think there should be any major technical difficulty with doing that (every interface member would get a vtable slot, but some would point to the static methods), and it could both make interfaces extensible and eliminate the need for 'partner' static classes to provide things like Enumerable<T>.Empty (as opposed to IEnumerable<T>.Empty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach gives you the best of both worlds - the flexibility of interfaces with the helpful option of a base class.

By *requiring* only that consumers implement your interface, you are not forcing them to lose the only inheritance slot open to their class (C# not allowing multiple inheritance).

But by additionally *offering* an abstract base class, you can give them a "leg up", perhaps by implementing some helper functionality that is likely to be a common requirement to most implementations of your interface - for example this could be achieved using a Template Method pattern.

There are several examples in the .NET Framework itself of both an interface and a base class being exposed. For example `System.ComponentModel.IComponent` and `System.ComponentModel.Component`

> Here is another question. If I implement an interface, should the
>   interface only contain methods that all sub-classes can do?

Yes. You're essentially describing the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: Thanks - I get asked this question quite frequently in interviews!

Comment: I updated my post with somethings that I think are benefits, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The interface would define the contract. Any implementer (either directly or via an abstract implementer) would conform to this contract.

An abstract class means you could reuse parts of an implementation across concrete implementations - you could have more than one abstract class, implemented differently.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming C# here because the other question had a C# tag*

The obvious benefit is that in the future you have another class, that already inherits from a base class, and you want to pass that to a method that accepts the . . .

You can't do put **first base class** in there, because C# doesn't all multiple inheritance, so you can never pass object that subclasses a different class in there.

You can however put **interface** in there, because the new object can always implement the Interface, even if it logically should derive from the base class.

Having both means the base class can implement the interface, that suits you now because you can put common logic in there, you don't need to repeat yourself, or have a heap of static methods in a "helper" class.

Also in the future if you have other classes that you want to use, they don't have to inherit the base class, then can just implement the interface.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: It makes sense.  I could only put 5 tags and it was a toss up between .NET or C# :)